# Laptop Stucks Power Button not responding

Tags: laptop, freeze

I am using Lenovo B560 Ci3 First Generation Laptop with 6GB RAM (2GB + 4GB). Sometimes my laptop stucks even power button also freezes along with keyboard and mouse-pad. To restart i have to put battery off and put it in again. The strange thing when laptop stuck its GUI (Windows 7 Screen Gadgets) works normally for-example it updates time. CPU Meter Gadget works normally.

When i insert external mouse in usb port it works. When i try to shutdown/restart my computer from external mouse laptop screen becomes white and freezes.

I also installed fresh windows 7 OS but still no luck.

Comment: Seems a problem with connection between the panel and the laptop, have you opened the case for any reason? they have a cable that connects the panel and keyboard+mouse on the board. or this is a faulty cable or the contacts aren't doing their job if you have spilled liquid over.

Comment: @emirjonb my laptop is undergone from Service two times... i used my laptop approx 12 hours daily and experience this situation once in two to three days

Comment: usually panel, mouse and keyboard have different connectors but this depend on models. if they have different cable and freeze at the same time, it should be a problem in motherboard. you can try to test it leaving one out. example remove the mouse, keyboard or front panel and leave the laptop on